# Setting up the priority in bazel test

Tags: unit-testing, bazel, bazel-rules

Is there any way to set up the order of tests executed first in bazel?

I would like to run some heavy tests first and assign lighter test later.

But, it looks like Bazel starts the heavier tests later, making the entire test slower.

Comment: @Vertexwahn Yeah, the question was actually about "priority" not actual execution order. But it seems like bazel does not support both features. Thank you :)